# How to convert line to a list

Tags: python, list, sorting, line

I used the following code to get the difference between each element in the list En. But answer comes as a line

```
En = [1,2,3,4,5]
for x in En:
    for y in En:
        if x !=y and x > y:
            z = x-y
            print(z)
```

The answer I got is in a line (Vertical)

I want the answer as a list: `[1,2,1,3,2,1,4,3,2,1]`

What should I change?

And can I get the list of items in ascending order?

Comment: Which programming language is that? Please specify in the tags.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add values of `z` in a seperate list using `.append()` method and then print that list.

```py
En = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

values_of_z = []

for x in En:
    for y in En:
        if x != y and x > y:
            z = x - y
            values_of_z.append(z)
          
print(values_of_z)
```

**Output:**

```
[1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

You can sort `values_of_z` by using `sorted()` function.

```
print(sorted(values_of_z))
```

**Output:**

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4]
```

Comment: This answer is really helpful. Thank you so much.

Comment: You're welcome. Please consider **upvoting** it. You can also refer [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)